# How to use an Nginx allow list by dynamic DNS instead of IP address?

Tags: nginx, dynamic-dns

I am running an Nginx web server on Ubuntu 20.04. In my virtual host configuration file, I have set an allow/deny directive to block all IP's except the specified IP from accessing a URL. My virtual host setting look like this:

```
server {
    # Restrict access to LAN & Personal IP's
    allow 127.0.0.1; # LoopBack IP Address
    allow 192.168.1.0/24; # LAN IP Address
    allow 123.456.789.102/32; # Home Public IP Address
    allow 111.222.333.444/32; # Work Dynamic IP Address
    deny all;
    error_page 403 =444;
...
```

The problem with this is that my "Work Dynamic IP Addresss" is infact dynamic, and changes often. So for a few days or so, I will be able to access the web page from my work IP address `111.222.333.444/32`. But then when the Work dynamic IP address changes to `555.777.888.999/32`, I can no longer access the web page from work since the my work public IP address has changed.

As of now, I have set up my work IP address with a Dynamic DNS provider. So my dynamic DNS address for work is `dansworkip.ddnsfree.com`. I would like to incorporate a dynamic DNS host address into Nginx's allow list so that when My work's public IP address changes, Nginx looks up the new IP address from the domain `dansworkip.ddnsfree.com`, and puts it into the allow directive.

I have tried something like this:

```
server {
    # Restrict access to LAN & Personal IP's
    allow 127.0.0.1; # LoopBack IP Address
    allow 192.168.1.0/24; # LAN IP Address
    allow 123.456.789.102/32; # Home Public IP Address
    allow dansworkip.ddnsfree.com; # Work Dynamic IP Address
    deny all;
    error_page 403 =444;
...
```

But when I try this configuration, Nginx won't start, and I get the following errors in my Nginx log:

```
[emerg] 10269#10269: invalid parameter "dansworkip.ddnsfree.com" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/www.mysite.com
```

My questions is, how can I incorporate Dynamic DNS into Nginx so that Nginx looks up the allowed domain's IP address and whitelists the IP address of my dynamic DNS hostname?

Comment: How dynamic is it? A straightforward solution would be to have a cron job that resolves your host and if the ip has changed put in into a file and reload nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Using an IP address as an authentication token is commonly considered bad practice. Nginx does not have the functionality to achieve what you ask for. If I really had to find a solution to the problem you posed, then I'd go with Alexey's solution proposed in comments, however Nginx does have a very useful authentication/authorization capability which allows you to [hand off the decision](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) to a web page of your choosing/design.

In there you can use whatever authentication rules / mechanism you can code. You can use session data (if your choice of tools supports this) but do consider whether any session identifier might conflict with that implemented by the application that you are providing a gateway for.

e.g., in PHP,

```
<?php
$ipdir="/var/www/access";
$TTL=600;

function deny_access() 
{
   header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
   exit;
}

function permit_access()
{
   print "";
   exit;
}

function refresh_config()
{
   // replace files in "/allow", delete aged files from "/deny"
   // then update timestamp on control file.
   // Implementation left as an exercise for the reader
}

if (time() - filemtime($ipdir . "/control.file") > $TTL) {
    refresh_config();
} 
if (file_exists($ipdir . "/deny", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    deny_access();
} else if (file_exists($ipdir . "/allow", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    permit_access();
} else {

}
```

An alternative approach (which may be more efficient based on multiple factors, but restricted to IP addresses) is to maintain [the lookup in nginx itself](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/denylisting-ip-addresses/) - with the maintenance of the list external.